# How to make a continuous rotation servo move 45 deg only when a button is released?

Tags: button, arduino, esp32, servo, arduino-c++

I have a program which updates every 100 ms due to a millis() function.
The program is waiting for a button to be pressed and when it does something happens.
Now, I want to know when the button has been released, wait about half a second, and then move the continuous rotation servo about 45 degrees.

How do I do that?
A part of my code is attached.

```c++
#define UPDATE_MS (100)
#define BTN_PIN (5)

bool btn_state = 1;
bool prev_btn_state = 1;

void loop () {
    if (millis() - previous_millis >= UPDATE_MS) {
        previous_millis = millis();
        btn_state = digitalRead(BTN_PIN);

        if (!btn_state) {
            //It does somethings - doesn't matter right now...
            prev_btn_state = 0;
        }
    }

    if (btn_state != prev_btn_state) {
        magazine_servo.write(45);
    }
    prev_btn_state = btn_state;
}
```

Comment: You might want to research the subject of *state machines* ("machines" not related to hardware in this case). When the button is released you enter a "wait" state where you wait for the timeout (500 ms) and then enter the "move servo" state, which moves the servo, and when done enter the "normal" state.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous rotation servos don't have position control.  Unless you have some sensor that can tell you how far the servo has rotated, there is no way to stop it at exactly 45 degrees.  If you watch how fast it rotates, then you can maybe estimate 45 degrees just by turning it on for the right amount of time.  But even with that it will slowly get further and further off.  If you want positional control then you either need a servo that gives positional feedback or you need a stepper motor where you can control how far it moves.